# docker- elasticsearch is stopping when i dockerize my service

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch which is running in docker is getting stopped when i run my service in docker.
if i run my service(spring boot app) first then if i run elasticsearch in docker , elasticsearch will never start in docker container? any idea about this?

is below is the problem?

```
{
   "type":"server",
   "timestamp":"2019-12-11T10:25:39,589Z",
   "level":"DEBUG",
   "component":"o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction",
   "cluster.name":"docker-cluster",
   "node.name":"179c5890f49c",
   "message":"All shards failed for phase: [query]",
   "cluster.uuid":"myyvQb8oS9qFjcCL4B41Sg",
   "node.id":"RVuYJJ_NQ3uygvgq3cM-dg",
   "stacktrace":[
      "org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException$1: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [type] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including details of how you're starting your application and Elasticsearch containers?

Comment: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. means that you are trying to aggregate on a text field, that is not possible. Could you please share your mapping and your aggregation?

Comment: It would help to see your ES error logs. This is a DEBUG message so obviously is not that important.